# Problem to download/install Psychtoolbox on Matlab (Ubuntu)

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, psychtoolbox

I can't install properly Psychtoolbox on Matlab.
When I use the DownloadPsychtoolbox, I get this message error

> Error: File: DownloadPsychtoolbox2.m Line: 1 Column: 32
>   Invalid expression. Check for missing multiplication operator, missing or unbalanced delimiters, or other
>   syntax error. To construct matrices, use brackets instead of parentheses.

Here is the code :

```
function DownloadPsychtoolbox ('/home/fh/Desktop')
```

I have also tried `function DownloadPsychtoolbox (['/home/fh/Desktop'])`
or whitout the ' nor [, but it does not work...
I already have installed the up to date subversion, and have tried to launch it through the terminal with `ptb3-matlab`, but once Matlab runs, it does not work neither.

The original script is `function DownloadPsychtoolbox(targetdirectory, flavor, targetRevision)`, with the target directory to fill, and if don't, it returns this error message :

> You did not provide the full path to the directory where Psychtoolbox should be
>   installed. This is required for Microsoft Windows and Linux installation. Please enter a full
>   path as the first argument to this script, e.g. DownloadPsychtoolbox('C:\Toolboxes\').
>   Error using DownloadPsychtoolbox (line 419)
>   For Windows and Linux, the call to DownloadPsychtoolbox must specify a full path for the location of
>   installation.'

So I don't know what is wrong with this PTB...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are editing the actual `DownloadPsychtoolbox` function. Instead, you want to call the `DownloadPsychtoolbox` function from the MATLAB commandline with your desired install path as a parameter, with no space between the function name and the parantheses:

```
DownloadPsychtoolbox('/home/fh/Desktop')
```

Comment: It doesn’t work, plus i don’t know why thèse is any space in my post, because there is not in the code, and i did a copy pasta... i have eventually switched the computer, thanks anyway !